# How to split a csv_file into two file: one containing 40% of the original data, the other 60%. The data should be shuffled first

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

I have a csv file. The columns are ['A' 'B' 'C'], and there are 1000 rows of original data.
A  B  C
1  0  1
-1 2  0
.
.
.
1  0  0.
So I need 40% of these data in one csv_file, 60 % in the other. But first, the rows must be shuffled randomly. Hopefully using the pandas module in python.

I tried

```py
Import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
np.random.permutation(df)
df[0:400].to_csv('filename1.csv')
df[401:].to_csv('filename2.csv')
```

but np.random.permutation(df) returns only arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

with shuffling before saving & complete snippet

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


per = 40
mask =int(len(df))

perdf=df.head(int((mask*(per/100))))

perdf =perdf.iloc[np.random.permutation(len(perdf))]
perdf.to_csv('40perdf.csv')


perdf60=df[:mask]
perdf60 =perdf60.iloc[np.random.permutation(len(perdf60))]
perdf60.to_csv('60perdf.csv')
```

Note: Not tested...Pls test it & let me know

Comment: 40perdf=df.head(int(len(df)*(n/100))), may I know what is n?

Comment: sorry It's typo it should be 'per`

Comment: Edited....Check know

Comment: It shows!"TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on RangeIndex with these indexers " on the line "60perdf=df[:40perdf]"

Comment: int(40perdf) try this in  df[:40perdf]

Comment: my bad sorrry 2 minutes...i done mistake

Comment: Tested & edited...Sorry for late

Comment: worked? Have u tetsed?

Comment: Yes, just now, I added "perdf60.to_csv('60perdf.csv',index=False)" to make the indices disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was, that You don't return result of permutation

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\temp\test1.csv", sep=',')
# source file like this
# A,B,C
# 0,1,1
# 0,0,0
# 1,1,0
# 0,0,0
# 0,0,1
# 2,0,0

df = pd.DataFrame( np.random.permutation(df))
df = df.rename(columns={0: 'A',1:'B',2:'C'})

split_place = int(df.shape[0]*0.4)
df[0:split_place].to_csv(r'c:\temp\filename1.csv', index=False, columns=None, sep=',')
# in file get somthing like
# A,B,C
# 0,0,1
# 0,0,0

df[split_place:].to_csv(r'c:\temp\filename2.csv',index=False,  sep=',')
# if don't need header, can use header=False,
```

more info bout saving to CSV in [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Comment: What if op have 2000 rows?

Comment: Thanks! But the new csv_file has been rid off the columns 'A' 'B' 'C', and a row of value '0' appears on the top.  How to avoid this situation?

Comment: split_place = int(df.shape[0]*0.4)
    df[0:split_place].to_csv(r'c:\temp\filename1.csv',index=False, sep=';')
    df[split_place:].to_csv(r'c:\temp\filename2.csv',index=False, sep=';')

Comment: still appears like this in new files                        0
0,1,1
0,0,0
1,1,0
0,0,0
0,0,1
2,0,0

Comment: @Apy_dum Did you add code below?? because I get A;B;C / 8;b8;cb8 /10;b10;cb10
# If you need same columns name, rename dataframe
df = df.rename(columns={0: 'A',1:'B',2:'C'})

Comment: Oh, sorry. I replaced the codes instead of adding below them.

Comment: @Apy_dum If You don't need columns name at all use header=False
df[split_place:].to_csv(r'c:\temp\filename2.csv',index=False, header=False, sep=';')
[pandas info about to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Comment: I do need the columns since I need to further analysis the two files. Also,  since the file is 0
0,1,1
0,0,0
Renaming the column will only change the '0' index to 'A', 'B' and 'C' are missing like   A
0,1,1
0,0,0.

Comment: @Apy_dum I think You need change separator to when read df to "," 
df = pd.read_csv(r"filename.csv", sep=',')
Because You get only 1 column, in place of 3

Comment: I don't understand how works accepted answer. @Apy_dum make attention, that this answer (writhed by @Bhargav) return first 40% of lines (with head command) in perdf and permute them. After that get all 100% lines in perdf60 and permute them. You get 40% +100% and first part always will by from first 40%. Double check this.

Comment: I just needed the idea, then I make some modification to get what I want. So it works

Answer (score 0):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.sample` to get shuffled 40% without replacement then drop from main table to get the 60%.

```
df_40 = df.sample(frac=0.4)
df_60 = df.drop(df_40.index)
```

Comment: Thanks! I just saw this, worked surprisingly well.